# Lost old MMS images; can't find in Google Photos

Tags: backup, mms, google-photos, google-messages

I have years-long Google Messages text threads that have many, many photos. I've changed phones a lot, and the images have always been retained in the threads. I believe I have always selected the Android Device folder for Messages to be backed up

But I just noticed those images are gone from my text threads, and I cant find any of them in Google Photos. I just to the date the photos came in, and they're not there.

So I'm wondering where these could possibly reside. It's hard to imagine they're all gone forever. I thought I was intentionally backing them up. (My pet sitter always sends the best photos. My dog recently passed away, and I'd like to find the photos without having to ask the sitter).

TL;DR: Lost photos from Google Messages text threads despite frequent phone changes and thought I had backed them up. Can't find them in Google Photos.